# Get EventMessage Associated with Event in MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am creating a service that needs to decline events, when certain conditions are met, from a room's perspective **and** update the event on attendees' calendars.

While [declining the meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-decline?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is simple, I am struggling to update the event on a user's calendar. I assume that I would do this using [update eventMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/eventmessage-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Right now I have the ID of the event that is declined and I need to associate that event with its eventMessage. Therefore, I am making the following request:

```
`/users/${roomEmail}/messages?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event($select=id;$filter=id eq ${meetingId})`
```

What I am trying to do is get all messages, then expand so that I see the events associated with each message, then filter each event by its ID until I find the event that I care about. Once I have that event, I can send an update to its eventMessage.

However, I get the error `"Parsing Select and Expand failed."`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the id is not a number value, I believe you may need to add single quotes around the meetingID parameter at the end.

```
`/users/${roomEmail}/messages?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event($select=id;$filter=id eq '${meetingId})'`
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/using-filter-expressions-in-odata-uris#referencing-different-data-types-in-filter-expressions

Comment: Thanks! That fixes error, but still having issues with query. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232471/expanding-and-filtering-ms-graph-api-does-not-work.