# Expanding and Filtering MS Graph API Does Not Work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to get an [`eventMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/eventmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) from a user's mailbox that is associated with a specific `event`.

I have the event's `iCalUId` but I am unable to filter on it:

```
/users/${roomEmailAddress}/messages
?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event($filter=iCalUId eq '${iCalUId}')
```

What I am trying to do is get all messages, then expand so that I see the events associated with each message, then filter each event to find the one I care about.

However, I get a response with all events and the filtering mechanism is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Graph doesn't support including a `$filter` in the `$expand`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues?view=graph-rest-1.0#query-parameter-limitations):

> `$expand`:
>
> - No support for `nextLink`
> - No support for more than 1 level of expand
> - **No support with extra parameters (`$filter`, `$select`)**

What you *can* do is leverage the [`$search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#search-parameter) parameter to parameter to find all of the event messages (`$search="kind:meetings`) and then `$expand` the associated event:

```
/me/messages?$search="kind:meetings"&$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, first I filtered then I expanded list

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sideID}/lists/{listID}/items?$filter=fields/{Name of Field} eq '{VALUE}'&$expand=fields